# React- render a component which only makes a Swal alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert2

I'm trying to render a component which makes a Swal alert and nothing more- it shouldn't return any HTML.

```
export default function AddPaymentNotification() {
useEffect(() => {
Swal.fire({
  title: 'text',
  icon: 'warning',
 })
}, []);
 return <></>;
}
```

The above code does makes no alert, just returns an empty element.

I know that i can just create the alert without a component, but i want to understand how to correctly makes this work.
What am i missing?

Comment: Does it enter the effect?  Have you put a breakpoint there?

Comment: It doesn't enter the effect

Comment: What you have there [should work fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-75930930-render-empty-component-0tkcjs?file=/src/App.tsx). You can also just return null instead of an empty fragment. But either way it should run the effect normally. There must be something else going on.